# ClassNotFoundException when trying to run pan.bat with cmd

Tags: pentaho, kettle, data-integration

I want to create a Windows script that runs a Kettle transformation (.ktr).

First, I tried to run my script but it does nothing. 
After that, I decided to try it by cmd, but it still is not working. It outputs a `ClassNotFoundException`:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.pentaho.di.pan.Pan/file:C:\data-integration\UpdateDBUrgencies.ktr
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at org.pentaho.commons.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:87)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
```

The cmd line I run is:

```
pan.bat /file:"C:\data-integration\UpdateDBUrgencies.ktr" /level:Basic
```

All I want is to have an script that executes UpdateDBUrgencies.ktr, so it can be run everyday using cron of Windows. How do I have to do it? Where is the problem in my command line?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As a personal experience with .BAT for running .KJB's on **windows**, i had several issues when using /file or /level, try changing your commandline for:

**Pan.bat -file:C:/data-integration/UpdateDBUrgencies.ktr "-level:Basic"**

I have begun using this format of command line for all my batches and it's been working without erros, i'm using version 5.3 though, i don't know if there are major differences in command line paramaters and such on newer versions.